# Google Chrome - Is this a bug of a feature?

Tags: google-chrome

There's something going on with the address bar in Google Chrome when the window is full screen:

[image: Highlighted]

[image: Not Highlighted]

It looks fine when windowed (not fullscreen):

[image: Not fullscreen]

It's not my monitor (I have 2, same on both) or my computer (doing this at home and at work).

Is there some logic to this or is this a bug?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us more about your system(s)? What OS/version do you have?

Comment: Which version of chrome do you have?

Comment: Windows 8 at home, Windows 7 Ultimate in work, Chrome 20.0.1105.2

Comment: The fact that you can screenshot it probably rules out your monitors and video cards. You're seeing what the computer is rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same thing on my PC in Windows 7 when a program (say, Trillian) is using transparency and my system turns off Aero Glass effects.  Maybe try to change your theme in Chrome?